# Spark File not found . works fine in local mode but failed in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

Hi every one ,
                        I have simple spark application in which I have few spring context and rule xml file . all these files are part of the projects and located under resource folder (reource\db\rule\rule2.xml) and its working fine in spark local mode . when I ran the same application in yarn cluster mode , its complaining that the file rule2.xml not found and its part of Maven built jar. do I need to specify the file in a different format for cluster mode ? do I need to make any changes for the application to work in cluster mode ? any help would be appreciated

Here is the code in which I am reading the xml file

```
 JaxbUtils.unmarshalRule(
            ByteStreams.toByteArray(
            Resources.getResource(String.format("db/rule/rule2.xml", id)).openStream()));

Here is the error log

/24 15:57:07 INFO storage.BlockManager: Registering executor with local external shuffle service.
15/09/24 15:57:07 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@bdaolc011node08.sabre.com:40589/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 0
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3132) called with curMem=0, maxMem=555755765
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 530.0 MB)
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 0 took 134 ms
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(6144) called with curMem=3132, maxMem=555755765
15/09/24 15:57:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 6.0 KB, free 530.0 MB)
15/09/24 15:57:12 INFO support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3c6db742: startup date [Thu Sep 24 15:57:12 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
15/09/24 15:57:12 INFO xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/rules-engine-spring.xml]
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/ere-spring.xml]
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'nativeRuleBuilder': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.sabre.sp.ere.core.loader.DroolsNativeRuleBuilder]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [spring/ere-spring.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [com.sabre.sp.ere.core.loader.DroolsNativeRuleBuilder]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [spring/rules-engine-spring.xml]]
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'rulesExecutor': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.sabre.sp.ere.core.executor.DroolsRulesExecutor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [spring/ere-spring.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [com.sabre.sp.ere.core.executor.DroolsRulesExecutor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [spring/rules-engine-spring.xml]]
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from class path resource [spring/ere-test.properties]
15/09/24 15:57:13 WARN support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Could not load properties from class path resource [spring/ere-test.properties]: class path resource [spring/ere-test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from class path resource [spring/ere-spring.properties]
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15/09/24 15:57:13 INFO jdbc.JDBCRDD: closed connection
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource spring/rule2.xml not found.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
at com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(Resources.java:152)
at com.sabre.rules.AppRuleExecutor.rule(AppRuleExecutor.java:50)
at com.sabre.rules.AppRuleExecutor.executeRules(AppRuleExecutor.java:39)
at com.sabre.rules.RuleComponent.executeRules(RuleComponent.java:43)
at com.sabre.rules.SMAAlertImpl$1.call(SMAAlertImpl.java:60)
at com.sabre.rules.SMAAlertImpl$1.call(SMAAlertImpl.java:37)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$4$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$4$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Input files have to be accessible on all worker nodes. It means you have to either copy files (see for example `--files` parameter for `spark-submit`) to worker nodes or use distributed files system.

Comment: When running on yarn you must specify local files as file://<filepath> eg. file:///tmp/foo.txt

Comment: tried to execute below code and got the same file not found error. JaxbUtils.unmarshalRule(
                ByteStreams.toByteArray(
                Resources.getResource(String.format("file:///db/rule/rule%d.xml", id)).openStream())); do i need to keep the same file in hdfs ?

Comment: any update on this issue ? I am kind of stuck with this issue any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your code inside main() as given below:

> JaxbUtils.unmarshalRule(
>               ByteStreams.toByteArray(
>               Resources.getResource(String.format(args[0], id)).openStream()));

So, you need to invoke the code as below:

> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files db/rule/rule2.xml mySample.jar rule2.xml

What it does? It tells yarn to deploy the code/jar in cluster mode and keep the file specified in "--files" on container. In cluster mode, container can be created in any one of the nodes in cluster. However, once it has been specified in "--files", you need to refer it by its name only rather than specifying fully qualified path.